# duplicate a git repository and split into two

Tags: git

My team currently use one TFS Git repository for devs (web/mobile) and tests (gherkin specs + automation code).

The dev team "follows" git flow branches convention, but the test team use completely different branches (which are never rebased or merged with the feature/develop/rc/master or any of our dev branches), so we would like to split the repository, keep the history and the branch like they are.

I tried a 1st option of changing my remote-url to a new TFS Git repo, and push. But that only pushed my current branch.
So I tried a 2nd option with

```
git clone --mirror current_repo_url
git push --mirror new_repo_url
```

Everything seems identical, and I have the whole history.
But now I read that other people on S.O. are doing that with git filter-branch and other "complicated" commands, is it needed? and what is the difference with the mirror I made? Does "mirror" means those repos will be synchronized forever and cannot change independently?

Later we will use that test repo as a submodule of the dev repo, and each team will clean its unused branches, but for now we only want hassle free migration (basically change remote-url and that's it), so is what I did ok ?

**Edit :**

I did not notice it, but the push --mirror returned the following error at the end, any idea of what these refs are ?

```
! [remote rejected]     refs/pull/2616/merge -> refs/pull/2616/merge (The current action can only be performed by the system.)
 ! [remote rejected]     refs/pull/2625/merge -> refs/pull/2625/merge (The current action can only be performed by the system.)
 ! [remote rejected]     refs/pull/2655/merge -> refs/pull/2655/merge (The current action can only be performed by the system.)
 ! [remote rejected]     refs/pull/2668/merge -> refs/pull/2668/merge (The current action can only be performed by the system.)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... we would like to split the repository, keep the history and the branch as they are.

What you did will work and there is no problem with it.

## Other options:

#### `filter-branch`

As you described above you can also use `filter-branch` which will result in rebase since it will update the old commits

#### `subtree split`

```
# split the "main repo" into smaller repos
git subtree --split .... <branch1>
```

The `git subtree --split .... <branch1>` command will "extract" all the commits made to a given folder and will place them in a new branch. The branch will contain all the content of the given path. This will also result in rebase as well since the history will be re-written

[image]